# Как наложить картинку на кнопку?

Tags: android, android-button

Я новичок в Android. Пытался чёт с background но чет не вышло
Код

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:layout_width="376dp"
android:layout_height="73dp"
android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="468dp"
android:
android:background="#F8F8F8"
android:backgroundTint="@+id/button2"
android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
android:text="Отделения и банкоматы"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:srcCompat="@+id/button2" />


<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView10"
android:layout_width="49dp"
android:layout_height="44dp"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/biglupa"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="30dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="277dp" />
```

Вот код, Когда накладываю любое изображение на кнопку она оказывается под ней.
Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Она под ней? Кто из этих дам изображение?

Comment: Поменяй их местами или добавь нужной вьюшке высоту по оси z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/button2"
  android:layout_width="376dp"
  android:layout_height="73dp"
  android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
  android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="468dp"
  android:background="#F8F8F8"
  android:backgroundTint="@+id/button2"
  android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
  android:text="Отделения и банкоматы"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
  app:srcCompat="@+id/button2" />


<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageView10"
  android:layout_width="49dp"
  android:layout_height="44dp"
  android:elevation="10dp"
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/biglupa"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottom="@+id/button2" />
```

`android:elevetion` в `ConstraintLayout` добавляет смещение по оси Z, но такой метод не всегда удобен, ибо она будет откидывать тень (ознакомьтесь с MaterialDesign). Лучше использовать правильную последовательность (кнопка выше в списке, будет ниже картинке на дизайне, увы точно не помню, вчера сам столкнулся с этой проблемой, не работал ни один из вариантов в чужом проекте. Решил только через: `android:elevetion`).

Для изменения положения картинки используйте: `android:layout_marginXXX="XX"` и/или добавление правой привязки и изменением `bias`. [Изучите.](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/489-urok-180-constraintlayout-osnovy.html)

P.S. Эта реализация конечно хороша, но не совсем правильна, лучше делать "CustomView" или использоввать `android:drawableStart/End`, но это плохо работает с кнопками, я кнопки в основном реализовую на основе TextView.

P.S.S. `Button` является наследником `TextView`